# Spring-WS SOAP Service Design - One vs Multiple operations

Tags: design-patterns, soap, wsdl, spring-ws

I am publishing a SOAP webservice using Spring-WS and would like to know the approach for designing a WSDL.

If my service has to account for four operations (like start, update, suspend and restart a service), should I have one WSDL with one operation (for example, EntertainmentService) and take the operations as a request  attribute or should I define one WSDL with multiple operations.

```
 <request>
     <type><!-- start | update | suspend | restart --></type>
     <name></name>
     <address></address>
     <services>
         <tv></tv>
         <internet></internet>
         <phone></phone>
     </services>
```

If the suggestion is to go with one WSDL with multiple operations, how do I specify the list of operations in Spring-WS. Currently, my spring servlet context has one DefaultWsdl11Definition and WSDL is generated at runtime.

```
<bean id="EntertainmentService" class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="schema">
        <bean class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema">
            <property name="xsd" value="/WEB-INF/schemas/entertainmentService.xsd"/>    
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="portTypeName" value="EntertainmentService"/>
    <property name="locationUri" value="/endpoints"/>
</bean>
```

If all the four operations use the same WSDL, is it much easier for the client (using the web service) to make one operation (with different ) than making calls to multiple operation. Is there any advantage to the second approach (with different operation for each request type).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is more a conception design rather than a webservice one. In general, I would say it is better to keep each operation atomic. In your case, it would mean that you would have as many operation as you have actions to execute.

On the long run, suppose you want to modify the "suspend" action by adding a number of day (suspend in xx days or suspend for xx days)

1. You will only have to modify the part related to the action suspend
2. You will only have to test the suspend action

I used a static wsdl when I used spring web-service. If you change your xsd, spring will know that there are several actions/operations.

Comment: Thanks for your response. When you say "if you change your xsd", did you mean having different xsd for each operation and tie in that for each wsdl?

Comment: @aprajitha I never used the dynamic wsdl part of spring but if in the javadoc you can specify either one xsd file or a collection of xsd files. So the answer to your question is yes.